# 14.04 Ubuntu black borders, black terminal

Tags: 14.04, window-manager, window

This problem is the same as described by:
[13.10 - Black borders, black terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360598/13-10-black-borders-black-terminal)

However, that solution does not work.  So I don't think it's a duplicate.  In fact, nothing listed in that answer helped.

Comment: The problem started after installing lib-txc-dxtn.

Comment: Errr.. have you tried uninstalling lib-txc-dxtn - or a different theme?

Comment: Yes.  I uninstalled lib-txc-dxtn.  I will try a different theme.

Comment: @Wilf: Changing themes also did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it by Re-installing the Nvidia Drivers,

Here the link.. Hope help you.. [How to Install Nvidia Drivers.](http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/)