# 14.04 - Black borders, black terminal

Tags: unity, 14.04, nvidia, graphics

This question is clearly realted to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360598/13-10-black-borders-black-terminal).

However, I tried the suggested approaches and neither of them worked.

Let me explain what happend:
I'm using an Asus notebook with an integrated NVIDIA GPU. However, I've only been using the Intel graphics and it worked fine. I needed the NVIDIA driver for CUDA, so I installed the matching driver from the NVIDIA website.
Afterwards, I could not log in ubuntu with a GUI, but only in text mode.
I then uninstalled all NVIDIA packages. However, I think that I broke something, because I have the same black boxes around all windows, as described in the referenced question.

Comment: This is a known bug in the Nvidia driver, see [bug #1292830 Huge black borders around windows after resuming](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1292830)

Comment: Hmm I don't see a solution that works for me. And as I did not have the problem prior to installing the NVIDA driver, I would like to go back to that state, espacially as I already uninstalled everything NVIDIA related.

Comment: [Remove nVidia driver and go back to Nouveau](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12937/remove-nvidia-driver-and-go-back-to-nouveau) or [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

Comment: Thank you, both of the suggested approaches did not work for me. I'm still stuck with the black boxes.

Comment: SOLVED.
I really tried everything I found regarding NVIDIA... But what fixed it for me was the answer of Asger Bjørn Jørgensen in this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449845/problems-after-upgrading-to-14-04-only-background-and-pointer-after-login

I was so close to giving up on linux even though I've been using it for 5 years now.