# Windows have black borders after hibernation Unity

Tags: unity, 14.04, nvidia, xorg, hibernate

when my 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 machine "wakes up" after hibernation, windows look like this:

[image: gigantic borders on all the windows]

The system is still usable, but it's really ugly and I believe that Linux is beautiful, not only because of its command line, but also because of its GUI. So there must be a solution for this.

I am using a Samsung R780 laptop, Nvidia GeForce GT 330M graphics card, Intel® Core™ i7 CPU M 620. I have a separate swap partition set up and I'm running the x.Org server with Unity 7.2.0 on top. I'm using the evil ;) Nvidia proprietary driver version 331.38, because open drivers don't work for me. Do you need any additional information?

When I restart the x-server and display manager, everything works fine again.

I didn't find anything on the web and I don't have a clue what could possibly cause this problem, so I'm very thankful for any help.

Comment: was asked and closed before: http://askubuntu.com/questions/501986/14-04-black-borders-black-terminal

Comment: Sorry for the double post, should I delete my question now?

Comment: Leave it open for now, just wanted to help you with your search. 
Another related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/360598/13-10-black-borders-black-terminal

Comment: Seems like I messed up my compiz configuration when upgrading to 14.04. Thanks to user164089 and this post ( http://askubuntu.com/questions/360598/13-10-black-borders-black-terminal ), I tried resetting my compiz settings and it works. Without the help of noleti I wouldn't have found that answer. **Thank you all for your help!!**

Comment: Can you tell me, how you restart the x-server and display manager?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a known bug in Ubuntu 14.04 => https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1292830, please vote for it by clicking the green text at the top of the page that says "This bug affects 69 people, but not you".

A temporary workaround is to go into a system terminal mode, careful with this as you need to know how to get back to the Unity desktop otherwise you will have to restart.

1. Press Ctrl + Alt + F6 (takes you to system terminal mode)
2. Press Ctrl + Alt + F7 (takes you back to the Unity desktop)

Comment: What is really annoying though is that when I am docked the key sequence actually puts it into sleep mode. Would love to know what is happening then.

Comment: Launchpad has issues with upvoting right now. Hope it's temporary...

Answer (score 1):

Answered by OP in comments.

> Seems like I messed up my compiz configuration when upgrading to 14.04. Thanks to user164089 and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360598/13-10-black-borders-black-terminal), I tried resetting my compiz settings and it works.
>
> [Kudos noleti](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506260/windows-have-black-borders-after-hibernation-unity#comment682476_506260) - I wouldn't have found that answer otherwise.