# Popup dialogs transparent instead of showing any content

Tags: unity, compiz, dialog, intellij

I used to think this was just an Eclipse bug, but it persist even after switching to IntelliJ Idea. I think this happens on other programs as well, but less frequently, and obviously matters far less.

[image: screenshot]

Is there any workaround for this or do I just have to switch OS or something? I tried disabling compiz window fading but that didn't do any help.

OS: Ubuntu 15.10
WM: Whatever version of unity that ships with the above
HW: Dell Latitude E7250 (non-touch, HD screen)

Comment: I have the same problem on eclipse and ubuntu 16.04 did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope.  It has just become less frequent since I updated to 16.04 but still happens time from time

Comment: Well I felt that it became more frequent since 16.04 for me but I didn't do real statistics.

Comment: I often get this with LibreOffice, but also other programs. I wondered if it might be a video card / OpenGL driver issue, or somehing like that... Usually if I repeat what I was doing, it doesn't happen the second time. Very intermittent glitch, quite annoying though.

Answer (score 2):

I have sometimes had a situation like this happen to me. Along with an equally irritating black dialog version.

I found a solution in the answer to this question: [13.10 - Black borders, black terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360598/13-10-black-borders-black-terminal)

Which was to restart unity. Pop open a terminal window and:

```
setsid unity
```

After things settle down, most dialog issues generally seem to have sorted themselves out.

Comment: Worked for me, however beware, IntelliJ will be terminated, along with presumably others.