# Unity Displays Black Borders Upon Return from Suspend?

Tags: 16.04, unity

If I close my laptop and then reopen it, unity will display black borders around windows that are open. Like: [image] Or: [image], restarting unity via command line by just typing unity seems to clear it up until the next suspend, but this is somewhat annoying. Is there any way I can fix it? I'm running 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360598/13-10-black-borders-black-terminal?rq=1). The last solution, making a css-file, mitigates the problem permanently but does not fix it. Restarting unity (write *unity* in a terminal window, fixes it, but only until the next suspend.